# Handling dependencies in Library projects

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-permissions

I have one Android [open source library project](https://github.com/Abhi347/NoobCameraFlash) in which I have been using a separate library for [logging](https://github.com/Abhi347/LumberJack) (Which is also developed by me).

The logging library is not that important, but it makes the development and debugging easier (Both for me and the user of the main library). 
I am using gradle (and Jitpack) to use both the libraries. Now the Logging library is actually having few extra permissions in manifest (For writing logs to file, not necessary for the main library).

Now one of the user asked me to remove the extra permissions. And I don't know how can I do that without removing the logging library (or changing the functionality in the logging library itself). 
I even realised that few people might not need the logging library at all, so is there a way I can make it optional, like if the user didn't include the Logging library in their build.gradle, it won't get imported which I can detect and not call the logging functions?

I know it sounds confusing, but I'd like to know how to decouple both the libraries. In fact please let me know if you know about any such example from any popular library too.

Comment: Well can't you make two versions of library like [Material Dialogs](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs) and few other libraries has

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can probably do both with some clever tricks.

**part 1. PERMISSIONS**

About the manifest permissions. It's pretty simple, do not add the permission to the logging library and instead, check it on runtime. Like this:

```
if (context.checkPermission(
              Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 
              android.os.Process.myPid(),
              Process.myUid()) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
      carry on with your write to disk operation ...
}
```

and then on your documentation you write that IF developers using the library wants to have a local logging, they have to declare WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE on the manifest.

**part 2. (not) IMPORTING THE LIB**

All I'm gonna write here is by heart and 100% NOT tested. There might (will) be some errors that you'll have to shift around, but hopefully I'll pass a solid idea.

First on the NoobCameraFlash lib you'll define `LumberJack` in the `build.gradle` file with `provided` instead of `compile`. This will make the compiler known about the `LumberJack` so compilation can pass, but it won't include it on the actual build.

Then create in your NoobCameraFlash library a class that is a mirror of the library funcionalities. Which means the methods `d(String, String)`, `e(String, String)` etc.

Then you in this mirror class you will something like the following to check if lumberjack is actually available.

```
private static boolean lumberJackAvailable = false;
private static boolean lumberJackTested = false;
private static boolean isLumberJackAvailable() {
   if(lumberJackTested) return lumberJackAvailable;
   lumberJackTested = true;
   try {
      if(Class.forName("") != null) {
          lumberJackAvailable = true;
      }
   } catch(Throwable e){
       // ClassNotFoundException, LinkageError, ExceptionInInitializerError
   }
   return lumberJackAvailable;
}

public static LumberJackMirror create() {
     // could also be a singleton
    if(isLumberJackAvailable() return new LumberJackMirror();
    else return null;
}
```

then of course you have to check `if(lumberJackMirror != null)`. So as you can see it's not the most straight forward way of doing things.

Another way that simplifies this a little bit is to create an interface in a different library, that both the mirror and the actual LumberJack implements and use the factory can return an empty implementation of the interface instead of having to null check all the time.

As well, include on the documentation, that if developers want to have the logging functionality they have to add it to the `build.gradle`. Something like `compile 'your_groud_id:lumberjack:version'`

**edit**

another common way of doing that is to make it explicit on the NoobCameraFlash initialisation code. Something like:

```
  NoobCameraFlash.config()
       .setLogger(new LumberJack());
```

so that forces developers to know about LumberJack instead of checking via `Class`. But that would mean you need some version of LumberJack that is not just `static` methods.

**end_edit**

But hopefully just the permission removal will be enough and you don't have to do this part.2 =]

happy coding.

Comment: I would not use `Class.forName(String)` unless you add a consumer proguard rule to keep that class.

Comment: @JaredRummler you're absolutely right. @noob will have to also explicit tell devs to add ProGuard rule. I personally believe the `config()` option with some logger interface is the cleanest. But I can see how it adds refactoring to the Logger library